# HTML + CSS - 2 DIVs That Resize

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a quick question about HTML and CSS. I thought this would be easy to track down, but it's turning out to be quite the challenge. Essentially, I have 2 DIVs that are side by side, one that is a fixed width and one that is dynamic. The one on the right is a fixed-width, 400px DIV that holds some basic information. The one on the left is supposed to just fill the rest of the page. But there's a catch, I want to be able to dynamically hide the right DIV at any time (using jQuery) and have the left one fill its space. I know that there's several ways to do it, and I already know a few. But I want to do as little CSS manipulation in jQuery as possible. Here's some sample code I have.

```
<body>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</body>

<style type="text/css">
    #left {
        height: 100%;
        margin-right: 400px;
    }
    #right {
        float: right;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

The problem with this is that the right margin is permanently set to 400px. So if the right side were to be re-sized (to 0 width), the 400px margin would remain. Essentially, I need a margin on the left that is the size of the div on the right.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the margin-right: 400px

See live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/uxCpy/1/

Comment: It's funny, because I have the exact same fiddle open (one that I made), but it wasn't working on my actual site. I actually found out that the bug was coming from some changes that were made to the JS code recently that I had forgotten about. But as far as my original question goes, this is the right answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle `#right` between `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`. This will hide the element without removing it from the layout.

JS:

```
$('#left').on('click',function() {
    $('#right').toggleClass('invisible');
});​
```

CSS:

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nkuv4/

Comment: This does not address the issue of the `margin` OP is using, which has been explicitly stated as being the problem, and not the toggling of visibility. Not to mention, your suggestion allows the element to still take up space in the layout, which is what the OP does not seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to make the other div to take up the full width, you will have to set the display to none. Change to `display:none` with jQuery and it will work and then when you need it to display, change to `display:block`

Comment: The other `div` will not take up the full width with your suggestion because of the margin OP has set, which OP has explicitly stated is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a possibility to nest `#right` inside `#left`, and then `float: right` it? If you make `#left` the entire width of the page, this should have the same effect.